# Tracking AWS resources across multiple AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I effectively manage AWS resources across multiple AWS accounts? For now, I want to:

- Get a list of resources like EC2, RDS etc.
- Perform basic actions like reboot/start/stop instances
- Schedule stopping of instances after office hours and start during office hours - Currently I have a CloudWatch Event triggering the stop/start of instances

What service should I be exploring? For all these tasks, I have successfully implemented them on 1 AWS account.

I've used AWS SDK to get the list of resources and perform actions on these. But the challenge is Lambda, I believe to do this, I need to install these functions and all the CloudWatch Alarms for all regions for all accounts? Is there a better way?

Will AWS Organizations solve this issue? My accounts are currently normal AWS root accounts

---

I am exploring using CloudFormation to deploy these Lambda functions to all accounts and regions. Is this the most effective way? Is there a better option? Some regions does not support Lambda so it means my tracking only works for regions that support it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to delegate access across multiple AWS accounts using IAM roles. Let's assume you have a lambda function which stops/starts EC2 instances after/during office hours. This means that you can have deployed the lambda in a  `master` account (your *1 AWS account*) and to call AWS APIs in other `managed` accounts. In the `master` account, you have deployed the function and its IAM `master` execution role. This role allows the function to assume another `managed` role deployed in `managed` accounts to call respective AWS APIs, e.g. boto3 ec2 client stop_instances or start_instances methods. The IAM `managed` role allows to call AWS APIs in the `managed` account and it is assumable by the function.

Terse examples of the IAM roles (AWS CloudFormation snippets):

```
    "MasterRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": "master_role",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
              },
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "master_assume_policy",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "sts:AssumeRole"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    "*"
                  ]
                }

              ]
            }
          },
          ...
```

.

```
    "AccountRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "RoleName": "managed_role",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": ">>> ARN_OF_MASTER_ROLE <<<"
                        },
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Path": "/",
            "Policies": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "managed_ec2_policy",
                    "PolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [
                            {
                                "Action": [
                                    "ec2:StopInstances",
                                    "ec2:StartInstances",
            ...
```

You also need to switch to the IAM `managed` role by calling `AssumeRole` API from the lambda function. There is a nice [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html) available describing this procedure. In summary, you need to assume the IAM `managed` role via STS which will return you necessary credentials to call API.

Here are some more links which may help you to understand IAM cross-account delegation:

[Delegate Access Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

[Creating a role to delegate permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html)

Regarding AWS Organizations, I think it can help you to manage  `managed` accounts in more central way. You can create SCPs or Service Control Policies which centrally control the level of access to AWS services from `managed` accounts. The policy specifies the services and actions that users and roles can use in the accounts. You can also automate creation of AWS `managed` accounts with CloudFormation and configure it as you need. This may include creation of IAM user, roles, policies etc. There is a nice article about it available on the AWS blog:

[AWS Organizations - policy-based management for multiple AWS accounts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-organizations-policy-based-management-for-multiple-aws-accounts/)